# creating persistent search bar in android

Tags: android-widget, android

I want a search box which sits on top of the layout like this:

[image]
http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search

I do not know whether I have to build it myself from scratch using text boxes, white frames etc., or there is already a built-in widget or an open source work.

Actually designing everything from scratch does not seem to me right. Because by doing so I would have a incompatible view or user experience in future android APIs.

What are the options available and what is the most adopted approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a library called persisten search which look likes google now, google play etc. have a look at it:  https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

Comment: unfortunately the owner hasn't uploaded it to maven. If you have the chance, give it an "upvote", maybe it helps :) https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch/issues/2