# Create persistent search in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, material-design, searchbar

I am trying to make a searchbar that looks like [this](http://imgur.com/ZKwzppi). Using a toolbar and an EditText with some images i can get close, but it seems like a lot of work for something that should be easier.

Comment: I'm afraid, creating of such search view is a handwork. You can make it a bit easier by using SearchView ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating persistent search bar in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288500/creating-persistent-search-bar-in-android)